# curses - addstr text is not visible in larger terminals

Tags: python, python-3.x, curses

I'm writing an IRC client that uses Python's curses library, but the server's response is not output properly on the screen.

Basically, the smaller my terminal, the closer the output is to what it should be:

[image: Full-sized terminal]

On a full-sized terminal (1366x768 resolution) there is basically no output

[image: Half-sized terminal]

On a half-sized terminal, there is much more visible output

[image: Quarter-sized terminal]

On a quarter-sized terminal, the program outputs everything that I would expect it to.

Based on this pattern, my best guess is some line-length issue, but I really have no idea what the problem is.

#### Source Code

```
import curses
import queue
import socket
import threading
import time

PAD_LENGTH = 1000

def main(stdscr):
    s = socket.create_connection(("chat.freenode.net",6667))
    s.settimeout(1.0)

    s.send(b"PASS hello\r\n")
    s.send(b"NICK testingclient\r\n")
    s.send(b"USER testingclient tclient tclient :Test Client\r\n")

    s.setblocking(False)

    curses.noecho()
    curses.cbreak()
    stdscr.nodelay(1)

    pad = curses.newpad(PAD_LENGTH,curses.COLS-1)

    top = 0

    while True:
        try:
            msg = s.recv(512).decode("latin-1")
            pad.addstr(msg)
        except BlockingIOError:
            pass

        kc = stdscr.getch()

        if kc != -1:
            k = chr(kc)
            if k == "q":
                break
            elif k == "j" and top < PAD_LENGTH:
                top += 1
            elif k == "k" and top > 0:
                top -= 1

        pad.refresh(top,0,0,0,curses.LINES-1,curses.COLS-1)

    s.close()
    curses.nocbreak()
    curses.echo()
    curses.endwin()

curses.wrapper(main)
```

#### Misc Notes

I'm using i3 and xterm on Arch Linux in VirtualBox

Comment: have you tried to save `msg` to a logfile? Are you sure the content size is actually different and not just looks that way?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian The contents of `msg` are correct throughout all three tests. This is purely a visual issue.

Comment: I normally use `lines, columns = stdscr.getmaxyx()` to get the size of the terminal. Might it be, that this differs from the size in `curses.LINES`/`curses.COLS`?

Comment: @Dave J They are equal

Comment: Ah. Too bad. Hoped that would make a difference ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by using `addstr` on a string with a carriage return character.

I don't know the specific behaviour of `\r` in curses, but changing the message to `msg = s.recv(512).decode("latin-1").replace("\r\n","\n")` has provided me with perfect output.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The LINES and COLS values are not *magic* in any sense; they are initialized by the curses library based on the terminal size (from the operating system), and can be overridden (usually) by setting environment variables (named $LINES and $COLUMNS).  For more information about that, read the manual page for [use_env](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_util.3x.html)

If your application is more readable with a narrower format, then you can always check the value of COLS in your script and limit the value which you pass to curses.newpad here:

```
pad = curses.newpad(PAD_LENGTH,curses.COLS-1)
```

say, to 40.  You should use your own variable (a copy of COLS) in that call and reuse it in the other reference to COLS here:

```
pad.refresh(top,0,0,0,curses.LINES-1,curses.COLS-1)
```

Manipulating this using environment variables is, as noted, something that you could do -- but it is not often used.  Keep in mind that if you set $LINES and/or $COLUMNS to *larger* values than what the terminal provides, the result will not be good.

Recap from comments (there are other pitfalls which may be relevant, but I do not have a suitable configuration for *testing* your script):

- The pad isn't the same chunk of memory as stdscr. A getch on a given window tells curses to refresh that window. So if there are pending changes on the window, it overwrites any other window as the curses library copies data to curscr.
- Another potential problem is if your addstr's write newlines. A newline in addch/addstr will clear the remainder of the line.

Comment: Sorry, I must not have mad my point properly. Running the program in a larger terminal results in some of the output being printed blank. Running it in a smaller terminal results in the output being printed properly. In both cases the code and data values are all the same.

Comment: The figures seemed to show the data simply not covering the lower part of the screen since it was stretched across a wider screen.

Comment: My comments, by the way, are made just from reading the source given. I see that your program is reading from stdscr, and painting on the pad.  Pads are a limited type of window, and the difference between input/output windows can overwrite text, which also can be a problem with this example.

Comment: The first image contains only two full lines of output; the beginnings of each are visible but not the ends (I'll figure out text wrapping later). The spaces above and below the two lines are created by `addstr` calls, but they should be text instead. Also, doesn't my code initialise the pad to the same size as stdscr? So how could there be a difference between the two?

Comment: I'll test if getch is causing the problem.